# How to remove hasMany id attribute from sequelize join?

Tags: postgresql, join, sequelize.js

I am attempting to join two tables defined below in a one-to-many relationship. One Characteristic to many ReviewCharacteristics. Using the following findAll function I am attempting to avg the values in the ReviewCharacteristics table. I have verified the necessary SQL command that should function as expected. Sequelize is including ReviewCharateristic.id in the selected attributes which is causing my grouping to fail.

Is there a way to specify just the avg value and not include the id from the ReviewCharacteristic table in the selected attributes?

```
exports.Characteristic = db.define('characteristic', {
  product_id: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    allowNull: false
  },
  name: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING(7),
    allowNull: false
  }
}, { underscored: true });

exports.ReviewCharacteristic = db.define('review_characteristic', {
  value: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    allowNull: false
  }
}, { underscored: true });

exports.Characteristic.hasMany(exports.ReviewCharacteristic, { as: 'rc' });
exports.ReviewCharacteristic.belongsTo(exports.Characteristic);
```

```
Characteristic.findAll({
  attributes: ['name', 'id'],
  where: {
    product_id: req.query.product_id
  },
  group: 'characteristic.id',
  include: [{
    model: ReviewCharacteristic,
    as: 'rc',
    attributes: [[Sequelize.fn('AVG', Sequelize.col('rc.value')), 'value']],
    required: true
  }]
});
```

I have also tried specifying `attributes: ['characteristic.name', 'characteristic.id']`

Current:

```
SELECT 
"characteristic"."name", 
"characteristic"."id", 
"rc"."id" AS "rc.id", 
AVG("rc"."value") AS "rc.value" 
FROM "characteristic" AS "characteristic" 
INNER JOIN "review_characteristic" AS "rc" 
ON "characteristic"."id" = "rc"."characteristic_id" 
WHERE "characteristic"."product_id" = '18078' 
GROUP BY "characteristic"."id";
```

Expected:

```
SELECT 
"characteristic"."name", 
"characteristic"."id",
AVG("rc"."value") AS "rc.value" 
FROM "characteristic" AS "characteristic" 
INNER JOIN "review_characteristic" AS "rc" 
ON "characteristic"."id" = "rc"."characteristic_id" 
WHERE "characteristic"."product_id" = '18078' 
GROUP BY "characteristic"."id";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone happens to stumble across this question and is dealing with the same issue here is the solution I found.

```
Characteristic.findAll({
  attributes: ['name', 'id', [Sequelize.fn('AVG', Sequelize.col('rc.value')), 'value']],
  where: {
    product_id: req.query.product_id
  },
  group: 'characteristic.id',
  include: [{
    model: ReviewCharacteristic,
    as: 'rc',
    attributes: [],
    required: true
  }]
});
```

The attributes must be specified as an empty array for the joined table in order to stop the addition of the ReviewCharateristic.id attribute in my case.